# Edit, Copy, Delete options missing for a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am working on a plugin development in WordPress and just created a table with code

```
global $wpdb;
    $createSQL = "
        CREATE TABLE `". $wpdb->prefix ."recipe_ratings` (
          `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
          `recipe_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
          `rating` float NOT NULL,
          `user_ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB ". $wpdb->get_charset_collate() .";
        ";

    require( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' ); // to include dbDelta fn which allows us to modify the wp database
    dbDelta( $createSQL );
```

But the table created does not show the edit, copy and delete options like the other tables. May be I need to enable something in the phpmyadmin interface but I am not sure what to do here.

**No Edit, copy, delete option:**

[image]

**Expected Edit, Copy, Delete option**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes auto increment field not required. Only need to mention primary key.

```
$createSQL = "
        CREATE TABLE `". $wpdb->prefix ."recipe_ratings` (
          `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
          `recipe_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
          `rating` float NOT NULL,
          `user_ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB ". $wpdb->get_charset_collate() .";
        ";

    require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' ); // to 
    include dbDelta fn which allows us to modify the wp database
    dbDelta( $createSQL );
```

Just mention "id" as a primary key. And no need to put forward slash ("/") before including "upgrade.php" file. Because "ABSPATH" returning the value with forward slash.

Comment: Yes auto increment is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added auto_increment on any field.Make one column as a primary key and auto_increment.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instruction and added one of the column as primary key. And it worked. Auto increment option was not needed.